# Disable Raid 5 on an existing system

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, software-raid, raid5

I have a server running in RAID 5 (software raid with 3 disks).
Is there a way to disable the RAID 5 and just work on 1 disk (without formatting the pc)?

(+Does changing RAID count as a hardware change and does it affect the Windows OS activation?)

Comment: You provide no concrete information about your RAID controller making your question difficult to answer, but generally RAID level migration scenarios are geared towards [expansion](http://serverfault.com/q/304641/37681) and will use more and not fewer disks.

Comment: Yes provide more information. Have you tried anything yet? Made some effort yet?

Comment: I think I can't give any extra details, sorry for this. but what i've learned so far is that I better format and setup everything from scratch because changing a RAID setup from one to another is rather a no-go. I think I'll go with the format server idea and temporary run my vm's on another server. (sorry but I'm not very familiar to RAID, so I think I can't provide extra details :s)

Answer (score -1):

In a simple manner? No. Windows RAID doesn't support the change you want.